# Ignore Null check at source , while Mapping methods with several source parameters

Tags: java, mapstruct

Team, I have a use case related to map struct . PFB my interface

```
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "source1.name", target = "name"),
    @Mapping(source = "source2.address", target = "address"),
    @Mapping(source = "source3.company", target = "company")
})
public SomeClass map(Source1 source1,Source2  source2,Source3 source3);
```

Everything works fine. But my issue is with the below snippet(***which is generated by the mapstruct based on the above defined interface***)

```
public SomeClass map(Source1 source1,Source2  source2,Source3 source3)(
        if ( source1== null && source2== null && source3== null ) {
            return null;
        }
```

Here My issue is I dont want to return null in case if source2 and source3 is null and rather I will map the available details from source1 and proceed. I have gone through the mapstruct docs, But unfortunately I couldn't find any possible solution for this.
Do we have any solution in mapstruct for the above usecase or do we need to write custom logic to handle the above case.
Any pointer here is much appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: For now I have decoupled this logic into separate methods based on source parameter and used @MappingTarget property  to map all the values to a single Object. But I just want to cross check if we have a better solution for this usecase, other than this.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for entirely. If `source1` is not null then MapStruct will use it to do the mapping. Perhaps you can provide an example of what you are expecting MapStruct to do

Comment: @Filip , Thanks a lot for taking your time in check my query.
Basically I'm trying to map a target object from 3 different source objects(or arguments. if you look at my example, its Source1 source1,Source2  source2,Source3 source3). My issue is , in the implementation class if one of the parameter(source1 or source 2 or source 3 is null), then it will skip the mapping and return the value as null(   extract from the generated class ---if ( source1== null && source2== null && source3== null ) {
            return null; 
        })

Comment: Option Iam looking for is, it should skip the mapping only if all the arguments are null. if first argument is null, then it should go ahead and do the rest of the mapping with argument 2 (offcourse if argument2 is not null)

Comment: The generated code will return null only if all of the source arguments are null. If any of them is not null then the generated condition does not match and it will continue with the mapping (not return null). I would suggest you to edit your question and write how you expect the condition to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here My issue is I dont want to return null in case if source2 and source3 is null and rather I will map the available details from source1 and proceed.

Looking at the generated snippet by MapStruct the exact thing that is being asked is generated.

```java
public SomeClass map(Source1 source1, Source2 source2, Source3 source3)(
    if ( source1 == null && source2 == null && source3 == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    // rest of mmapping
}
```

This means that if `source1` is not `null` and `source2` and `source3` are `null` then then mapping will not return `null`, but it will use `source1` to do the mapping

Comment: No that is not right. The result will be null when  source1, source2 and source3 are null in the same time